# Impute missing values in a Pandas dataframe column depending of the most frequent value grouped by a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, null

I'm trying to impute the missing values in the column A with the most frequent value of the same column, but depending on how it is grouped with the column B.
Let em explain better:

This is part of my dataframe:

```
    col_A    col_B                
      8        31
      7        30
      20       83
      NaN      5
      8        31
      9        34
      37       158
      ...      ...
```

If I do a `df.groupby(['Col_B','Col_A']).size()`, I get that:

```
col_A    col_B 
  1        8       1
  5        1       10
           5       2
           7       6
           8       5
  6        8       1
  ...      ...     ...
```

So, if my column A has a missing value and the column B has a 5, I want to impute '1' because it is the most frequent value in column B for the 5 in column A.

I obteined a separate dataframe with the explained relation like this:

```
indx_lst=df.groupby(['Col_B','Col_A']).size().to_frame().index.to_list()
A_list=[]
B_list=[]

for i in indx_lst:
    x,y=i[0],i[1]
    if x in B_list:
        pass
    else:
        B_list.append(x)
        A_list.append(y)

A_col_null_imput=pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([B_list,A_list]),columns=['B_most_freq','A_imputer'])
```

I'm totally lost right now. How can I impute the nulls now? Is there a direct way to do it without all these dirty mid steps?

Comment: What if there is not a unique maximum count?  I.e., if you want to impute a `col_A` value with a `col_B` value of 7 and there are multiple `col_A` values with the same maximum _"pair"_ count of 9, which do you pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the groupby along with transform and fillna to achieve this without creating separate DataFrames.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'col_A': [8, 7, 20, np.nan, 8, 9, 37],
        'col_B': [31, 30, 83, 5, 31, 34, 158]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a function to impute NaN values with the most frequent value in the group
def impute_most_frequent(group):
    mode_value = group.mode().iloc[0] if not group.mode().empty else np.nan
    return group.fillna(mode_value)

# Apply the function to col_A grouped by col_B
df['col_A_imputed'] = df.groupby('col_B')['col_A'].transform(impute_most_frequent)

print(df)
```